# How to understand signal inversion and current flow through OTA?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, ota

In the following example schematic for an OTA, transistor M4 is said to be non-inverting input while M3 is the inverting input. The given explanations are short and i find them rather unclear.

[image: OTA schematic]

M4 is said to be non-inverting because: M4 and M8 are in common source, thus 2 inversions produce a non-inverted signal. But aren't M10 and M7 in common source too?

M3 is said to be inverting input because: M3, M6 and M10 are in common source configuration, thus resulting in 3 total inversions. Isn't M5 common source too?

Why do we account for M9 in the case of M3 input but not for M10 in the case of M4 input?

How does the current flow through such a device?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *But aren't M10 and M7 in common source too?*

and

> *Isn't M5 common source too?*

Just because M7 (or M5) use a common source connection doesn't necessarily mean they produce an inversion - their drains and gates are connected together and this means that they don't have any inverting qualities about them at all. They are wired as MOSFET diodes: -

[image]

and: -

[image]

<sub>The quote immediately below was copied before the OP corrected the question following my observation. This has caused me to edit my answer.</sub>

> *M3 is said to be inverting input because: M3, M6 and M9 are in common
> source configuration*

No, M9 is a MOSFET connected diode as per M5 and M7.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. You are right, M9 is in diode configuration. I've mistakenly written M9 instead of M10. The teacher said that M10 is the 3rd inversion of the signal entering M3. I have another question that i hope makes sense and isn't stupid: the current inverted by M6 flows through M10 and 'goes up' towards Vout?

Comment: M6 doesn't invert current - its drain inverts its gate voltage. When M6 conducts less current, M10's gate voltage is reduced and M10 is turned off more. This results in M10's drain voltage rising. So if M3's gate voltage goes down, then M10's drain voltage goes up (aka inversion).

Answer (score 0):

The only inverting voltage transistors are M4 & M8. Thus the non-inverting input is inverted twice.

The inverting input thru M3 does not invert as a differential pair thru the sources M3& M4 thus is only inverted by M8.

All others are used as current source /sinks/mirrors or bias are unipolar.